# "Data roaming" unchecked but connected to foreign network for data anyway

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, mobile-network, verizon, roaming

I am using a Galaxy Nexus LTE running Jelly Bean 4.2.2 with service from Verizon Wireless in the U.S. In Settings > Wireless & Networks > Mobile networks, I have:

- Data enabled: on
- Data roaming: off

I have flown to Canada twice recently. Both times, I turned my phone on to discover that I was getting new email through data roaming via a Canadian network, and was later billed accordingly. This happens despite the fact that I have Data roaming off. I have to turn Data enabled to off or go to Airplane Mode to get the phone to stop using data roaming.

Is there a way to actually disable data roaming so that I can set it and forget it?

Comment: Does your phone know that it is roaming when it is roaming? Usually it will say `Extended 4G` instead of `4G` or `Extended 3G` instead of `3G` etc.

Comment: There is a little "R" next to the signal bars when I am roaming.

Comment: Do you have root?

Comment: No. I do have Developer Mode enabled.